# How does the `success` function work and how can I imitate it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I'm developing a validation framework and need a boolean result to know if the validation was successful or not.

Here is a quick look of what I'm doing:

```
Stone.Validation({
 id:  "#InputTextId",//the id of the input you want to validate
 DataType: "string",//the Data Type of want to valide(string and integer for now are avaiable)
 MsgOk: "Correct",//optional: the msg you want to display if it is a string
 MsgWrog: "* Check this field",////optional: the msg you want to display if its not a string
 Destiny: "#someDivID",//the id that will some the correct of error message
})
```

I don't know how to disable form submission if validation failed. It just returns the message but not a boolean value or something like that.

Example of what im looking for:

```
Stone.Validation({
 id:  "#InputTextId",
 DataType: "string",
 MsgOk: "Correct",
 MsgWrog: "* Check this field",
 Destiny: "#someDivID",
 success: function(results)
{
   if(results)
    {
      //submit will work
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Why are you using HTML ids without jQuery?

Comment: Is there any problem if i use it??

Comment: Yes. When you refer to HTML ids you need to add $("#id-name") to have it recognized by jQuery.

Comment: OMG, i didint know that

Comment: wait a minute, you are telling me that if i use # in any of my code, JQuery has to recongnized?? Why i cant use whatever sign i want and specialy that sign???

Comment: Because # is specifically reserved for ids in the HTML/CSS DOM and jQuery uses the same DOM names.

Comment: lol i understood you question in the wrong way, it works without jquery my friend

Comment: OK, in that case I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking.

Comment: Let's clarify this ID thing first: `#myid` actually comes from CSS. It works in jQuery (`$('#myid')`) and with the native `document.querySelectorAll('#myid')`. But this will fail:  `document.getElementById('#myid')`. It should be `document.getElementById('myid')`. All that considering the markup is something like `<div id="myid">...</div>`.

Comment: i need the success funcion return true or false value to proceed with the validation

Comment: Maybe the answer I posted will help. Maybe it won't. You should add more info about how your current code works (how/where it's called, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To control form submission, you have to use the form's submit event. Here is how to do that with jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    // validate your form first
    if(!formIsValid) {
        // if validation didn't pass, cancel submission
        return false;
    }
});
```